# ipad Tabbar Customization Notworking

Tags: ipad, ios5, uitabbar, tabbarcontroller

I want to Customize the tabbar of iPad. I have attached The image for Clarify my issue.

Currently My Tabbar Like this :

[image: Currently My Tabbar Like this :]

I want Like this.

[image: I want Like this.]

I have Taken Custom Background Image for tabbar and using the following Code.

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
 {

NSUInteger index=[[tabBarController viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewController];

switch (index) 
    {
        case 0:
            [_tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_act11.png"]];

            break;
        case 1:
            [_tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_act22.png"]];
            break;
        case 2:
            [_tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_act33.png"]];
            break;

        case 3:
            [_tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_act44.png"]];
            break;

        case 4:
            [_tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_act55.png"]];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


    }
```

From the Above Code it It shows the tabbar as i want But , User interaction not working properly.I m unable to select Propertab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize **tabBarItem** for each view controller not the whole tabBar at once.
For this you can use methods from **UITabBarItem** header. Following should help you:-

```
- (void)setFinishedSelectedImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:(UIImage *)unselectedImage NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

You can customize **each viewController's tabBarItem** using above, before adding them to the tabBarController.